# How to validate empty and proper select option in PHP

Tags: php

Using following code to validate select and proper select of option, I am having issue on validating the element in PHP:

1. If I do not select any thing (with default novalue option ) I am getting the error message
2. Even if I select another option,again I am getting the not selected error message besides the `$select` is not loading to `$_POST['select']`

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
$select = "novalue";
$select_err = "";

if($select == "test"){
       $select_err = "Please select an option.";
} else{
       $select = $_POST['select'];
}
?>

<html>
   <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
     <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($select_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
       <label>Select Option</label>
       <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
         <option value="novalue" <?php ($select == 'test')? 'selected' :''; ?>>Choose...</option>
         <option value="Goa" <?php ($select == '1')? 'selected' :''; ?> >Goa</option>
         <option value="Kashmir" <?php ($select== "2")? "selected":""; ?> >Kashmir</option>
         <option value="Rajasthan" <?php ($select == "3")? "selected":""; ?> >Rajasthan</option>
       </select>
       <span class="help-block"><?php echo $select_err; ?></span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" name="submit">
     </div>
   </form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a name="select" in your  tag. A form is only submitting elements that have a name set.

Furthermore, you don't use the POST-value in your first lines. Change to:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $select = $_POST['select'];
    $select_err = "";
    
    if(empty($select)){
           $select_err = "Please select an option.";
    } else{
        // here do stuff with the value...

    }
}
```

and then should fix that the form should only be shown if there is no post at all. If there is postdata, you should do something with it and show a response.

Comment: Thanks mous, I fixed this but still not getting proper return! still getting the error message and not value for select

Comment: @Behseini I added some extra stuff in my answer.

Comment: @jay thank you for suggesting your change. I accepted. But now you put it in as an answer yourself. Seems a bit double...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery(client side) you can show your error message.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            
            $select = $_POST['select'];
            
            // here do stuff with the value...
    
    }
?>


<html>
   <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
     <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($select_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
       <label>Select Option</label>
       <select class="custom-select" name="select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
         <option value="test">Choose...</option>
         <option value="1">Goa</option>
         <option value="2">Kashmir</option>
         <option value="3">Rajasthan</option>
       </select>
       <span class="help-block" id="error_span"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" style="display:none" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" name="submit">
     </div>
   </form>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" onclick="form_submit()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" name="submit">
    </div>

</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function form_submit(){
    var selected_val = $("#inputGroupSelect01").val();
    
    if(selected_val=="test"){
      $("#error_span").text("Please select an option.");
    }
    else{
      $("btn_submit").click();
    }
  }
</script>
```